# why do I get this error on @import declaration?

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm trying to use LESS to compile my webpage styles. I've included the styles and scripts as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/styles.less" />
```

Scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            less = {
                env: "development",
                async: false,
                fileAsync: false,
                poll: 1000,
                functions: {},
                dumpLineNumbers: "comments",
                relativeUrls: false,
                rootpath: ":/localhost/formadominio/"
            };
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/less.min.js"></script>
```

In my styles.less file I do this:

```
@import 'variables.less';
@import 'mixins.less';
@import 'iconos.less';
@import 'base.less';
@import 'home.less';
```

But Chrome throws me the following error: SyntaxError: Cannot read property 'importMultiple' of undefined

In firefox: SyntaxError: b is undefined

What am I doing wrong? any help?

Comment: It looks like instead of the actual Less files your server returns 403 or 404 thing (and the compiler obviously fails parsing it).

Comment: All my less files are in the same directory of the styles.less, Browser console doesn't throw me any 404 or 403 error.

Comment: Also could be something like [#2373](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2373).